# NetBeans: Use environment from .bash_profile when running Maven commands

Tags: bash, macos, maven-3, netbeans-8

I have a .bash_profile with environment variables I want my IDE, NetBeans, to see during execution but doesn't seem to work.

Any hints on how to get the IDE to see this?

Comment: Which version of NetBeans?

Comment: 8.2, 10. Don't think it matters much.

Comment: Well, I know for certain that my answer below works on 8.2 but haven’t tested yet on version 10.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding “. ~/.bash_profile” at the end of your netbeans-/etc/netbeans.conf?

Comment: It doesn't allow me to update this file on mac saying I don't own it.